# WCF: The message could not be processed: 

Tags: wcf, security, wshttpbinding

I have created a WCF service which I am hosting as an application under my site on an IIS7. It is running on one server and now I am trying to make it run on a second server. When I call the service I get the following error:

> The message could not be processed.
>   This is most likely because the action
>   \u0027http://tempuri.org/IMyService/myMethod\u0027
>   is incorrect or because the message
>   contains an invalid or expired
>   security context token or because
>   there is a mismatch between bindings.

I have set the security in the **wsHttpBinding** to **None**, so in my naive mind I conclude that it is not a security problem.

What might I do wrong and how should I proceed to determine what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the same channel URI. Change it for second server. You can't use same URI for boths.